# How to generate .cer or .pfx file to create a Certificate in Azure Automation

Tags: azure, automation, certificate, pfx

I hope I could get some advice on how to obtain .cer or .pfx file in order to create a new certificate with the Azure Portal. I'm fairly new to Azure Automation and I'm following Microsoft documentation on managing certificates, but I just cannot find a clear, newbie friendly explanation on how to generate a .cer file in order to use it later for the creation of a certificate.

Any advice/help is very appreciated.

Comment: Use the tool `openssl req` and `openssl pkcs12` to create a private key (.cer), and certificate (.crt) which combined result in .pfx. There are lots of openssl examples. Good getting started article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs